# DELPHI Firemonkey FMX Android - Calling another app's activity

Tags: android, delphi, android-activity, firemonkey

I am developing an android app with firemonkey. DELPHI 10.4

There is a development case that needs to be answered by calling an activity in an external app, so I wrote the source by looking at the source of a sample developed with android (which works well), but the app dies and cannot be called.

The key is to call it as if you are one with your app with the ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP Flag.

When I try DEBUG mode,
It's app dies after calling normally.

I couldn't even change the settings in the manifest or various sources.

=========================================================

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  PackageManager : JPackageManager;
  ComponentName : JComponentName;
  ResolveInfo : JResolveInfo;
  stelegram : String;
begin
  stelegram := '010101';
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  ComponentName := TJComponentName.Create;
  try
    ComponentName := TJComponentName.JavaClass.init( StringToJString('com.ksnet.kscat_a'), StringToJString('com.ksnet.kscat_a.PaymentIntentActivity') );
    if ComponentName <> nil then
    begin
    Intent.SetAction( TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN );
    Intent.SetFlags( TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP   );
    Intent.AddCategory( TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );
    Intent.SetComponent( ComponentName );
    Intent.PutExtra('Telegram', StringToJString( sTelegram ) );
    Intent.PutExtra('TelegramLength', Length( sTelegram ) );

    if MainActivity.getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, TJPackageManager.JavaClass.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size > 0 then
    begin
      SharedActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent,1);  
    end
    else
      memo1.Lines.Add('INTENT 1 Faile');
    end;
  Except
  on e: Exception do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add( E.Message );
    end;
  end;

end;
```

==============================================================

```
    // IC Approval ( ancroid sample source )
    Button.OnClickListener btn1OnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText et = findViewById(R.id.spet1);
            mDeviceNo = et.getText().toString();
            makeTelegramIC("1");
            // makeTelegramVANTR();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.ksnet.kscat_a","com.ksnet.kscat_a.PaymentIntentActivity");
            mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            mIntent.setComponent(componentName);
            mIntent.putExtra("Telegram", mRequestTelegram);
            mIntent.putExtra("TelegramLength", mRequestTelegram.length);
            startActivityForResult(mIntent, 0);

            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.cardsvtv1);
            String str = Util.HexDump.dumpHexString(mRequestTelegram);
            tv.setText(str);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your Delphi code is missing the 'Intent.PutExtra()' lines. What errors are produced when you run Monitor.exe?

Comment: added to the putExtra source and
Symptoms in debugger are SharedActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent,1); is normally called and passed, but the external app is not displayed and the app is killed.
one more question
Is it possible to call FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP Flag?